# Error en detectar URL desde un bucle/while

Tags: php

En mi base de datos se permite ingresar imágenes de manera local -> `imagen.png` o desde una `URL` -> `https://dominio/ruta/imagen.png`, la idea principal es poder detectar si en dicho dato inicia con: `http`, `https`, `ftp`.

Mediante el siguiente código obtengo dicha respuesta sin ningún problema:

```
$image = "http://www.example.com";

$UrlImage = $image;
if(preg_match('/^(http|ftp|https)\:\/\/+[a-z0-9\.\_-]+$/i',$UrlImage)) {
    //echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';
    echo 'URL';
} else {
    //echo '<img src="assets/img/website/catalog/'.$image.'">';
    echo 'No URL';
}
```

Cabe recalcar que la variable `$image` puede almacenar dos valores imagen local `1.png` o url de imagen `http://dominio/ruta/1.png`

## El error

Al ejecutar dicho ejemplo dentro de un bucle `while` me muestra como resultado que todo es `No URL` incluso la que si son `URL` me muestra que es `No URL`, este es mi código:

```
$stmt->bind_result(
                    $id_product,
                    $image,
                    $product
);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    $UrlImage = $image;
    
    if(preg_match('/^(http|ftp|https)\:\/\/+[a-z0-9\.\_-]+$/i',$UrlImage)) {
        //echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';
        echo 'URL';
    } else {
        //echo '<img src="assets/img/website/catalog/'.$image.'">';
        echo 'No URL';
    }
}
```

Me pueden explicar como solucionar el problema, que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: @BetaM No entendí... la variable `$image` puede tener una imagen local o una imagen url, esa variable es de un listado de productos de la base de datos, ya la vuelvo a editar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error está en la expresión regular que usaste

```
/^(http|ftp|https)\:\/\/+[a-z0-9\.\_-]+$/i
```

que claramente va a coincidir con una URL que sólo tiene el dominio, como en el caso `"http://www.example.com"`, pero no va a coincidir con una ruta más larga como en  `"http://dominio/ruta/1.png"`

**¿Por qué?** Porque `a-z0-9._-` son los caracteres permitidos, y no contiene a la `/` dentro de estos.

En cambio, si lo agregamos a esa clase de caracteres, la siguiente expresión sí va a coincidir:

```
/^(https?|ftp):[-a-z0-9._\/]+$/i
```

---

**Otra forma** de validar URLs, sin preocuparte por la sintaxis de regex es usando [filter_var()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filter-var.php):

```
if (filter_var($UrlImage, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false) {
    echo 'URL válida';
}
```

y en caso de que te ayude, también se pueden pasar [opciones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) como 3er parámetro a `filter_var()`:

```
FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED   Sólo si respeta el RFC
FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED     Debe contener el dominio (www.ejemplo.com)
FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED     Debe contener una ruta (/ruta/archivo.html)
FILTER_FLAG_QUERY_REQUIRED    Debe contener parámetros de consulta (?a=busqueda)
```

Comment: Funciono sin problemas, gracias.

Comment: Me alegro! Que disfrutes armando el resto del código!

Answer (score 1):

Lamento diferir de la segunda parte de la respuesta de @Pollo con respecto al uso de `filter_var()`, ya que esta función consideraría como válida una URL como esta: `ttp://www.example.com`. Además, la intención no es validar una URL realmente, sino verificar si la misma empieza por `http`, `https` o `ftp`.

Si quieres evitar el uso de expresiones regulares, esto podría hacerse fácilmente usando [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). Pasándole la bandera `PHP_URL_SCHEME` obtendrías sólo la primera parte de la URL y podrías verificar el dato contra un array que contenga los valores de tu lista blanca usando [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php).

El código quedaría así:

```
$UrlImage = 'https://www.example.com';
$whiteList=array('https','http','ftp'); 
if (in_array(parse_url($UrlImage, PHP_URL_SCHEME), $whiteList)) {
    echo "Ok"; #Actuar en consecuencia
}
```

Para **simplificar** y/o crear un **código portable**, puedes crear una función que devuelva un booleano e invocarla desde dentro del bucle, algo así:

```
function isSchemaValid($url) {
    $whiteList=array('https','http','ftp'); 
    return (in_array(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME), $whiteList)); 
}
```

Si las listas blancas varían según el contexto puedes sacar `$whiteList` de la función y ponerlo como parámetro, entonces declararías `$whiteList` en el contexto.

Para usar la función en el bucle:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {    
    if(isSchemaValid($image)) {
        //echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';
        echo 'URL';
    } else {
        //echo '<img src="assets/img/website/catalog/'.$image.'">';
        echo 'No URL';
    }
}
```

OBSERVA que en el `while` estoy pasando `$image` a la función, pues **es redundante hacer esto:  `$UrlImage = $image;`**, porque el dato ya lo tienes en `$image`.

Comment: La pregunta tampoco era cómo verificar el protocolo de la URL. Se preguntaba por cuál era **el error** en el código, que no estarías respondiendo acá. La segunda parte de la respuesta era anexa, y ofrecía una alternativa que para los fines prácticos de diferenciar entre 2 alternativas funciona, tanto como tu respuesta. Es cierto que `filter_var()` se queda corto a la hora de validar y que `parse_url()` es más exhaustivo. Gracias por agregar la info.

Comment: @Pollo en el planteamiento de OP queda claro que se quiere verificar si la URL empieza por uno de estos tres valores: 'https','http','ftp' y se pregunta por una manera de solucionar el problema. En mi respuesta simplemente indico un modo de solucionarlo, con la intención de aportar una vía alternativa. Si OP u otro usuario con un problema parecido quieren optar por esta vía, es totalmente válida, sin necesidad de usar REGEX.